# Why can't Qt build my project after including a QStackedWidget-inherited class?

Tags: c++, qt5, qwidget, subclassing, qstackedwidget

I want to subclass the "QStackedWidget" class to add some public slots but when I add its header and source to my Qt project, my project can't be built completely and after showing many compiling errors and warnings, Qt gets crashed.

This is my QStackedWidget-inherited class header below:

```
#ifndef QSTACKEDWIDGETV2_H
#define QSTACKEDWIDGETV2_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QStackedWidget>

class QStackedWidgetV2 : public QStackedWidget
{
public slots:
  void GoToNextPage();
  void GoToBackPage();
  void JumpToPage(qint32 index);
public:
  QStackedWidgetV2();
  ~QStackedWidgetV2();
}

#endif // QStackedWidgetV2
```

And these are some of the given compiling and warning errors. However, Qt showed me a lot of other errors but they were similar:
[image: s]

Comment: Looks like maybe some of your Qt header files got corrupted somehow?  You might have to open qstackedwidgetv2.h in a text editor, see what file is #include'd at line 5, and then check out that file to see if there are stray characters in it.

Comment: offtopic: `Q` is a prefix for a library (here Qt) - this was common technique used before namespaces were introduced. So basically you should never use this prefix - doesn't meter what you are inheriting.

Comment: The stray errors indicate you have some unexpected characters in the Qt header. Did you accidently edit the `QStackedWidget` header file while debugging or something?

Comment: Instead screenshot please copy text from "compiler/build output" window - there should be errors in text format.

Comment: offtopic2: `Q_OBJECT` macro is missing

Comment: On error: your source file most probably was saved with invalid encoding. `stray '\xxx' in program` means that compiler encounter character invalid for current encoding. Probably is some step you were using none English characters or you did something strange.

Comment: @MarekR, adding 'Q_OBJECT' to the class declaration didn't solve the problem, either. I did it, but I'm still getting the same errors and warnings.

Comment: The Q_OBJECT bug is independent of the corrupted / modified Qt header problem.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner, you're right. I changed my platform and ran Qt again and the problem is solved.